# How to list all entries in tags

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

There is a line `'/home/pc/test'`,
and words in the tags `'[/ alseko] [/ logs] [/ archive]'`
How to get the expected result =

```
[/home/pc/test/alseko][/home/pc/test/logs][/home/pc/test/archive]
```

My code, I'm trying to find:

```
select '[' || '/home/pc/test' ||
       ltrim(substr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]',
              instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]', '['),
              instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]', ']')),'[')
from dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and combine the paths using `LISTAGG`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3db1/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ("LINE" varchar2(13), "TAGS" varchar2(31))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("LINE", "TAGS")
         VALUES ('/home/pc/test', '[/ alseko] [/ logs] [/ archive]')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT '[' || LISTAGG(paths, '][') WITHIN
GROUP (
        ORDER BY NULL
        ) || ']' as all_paths
FROM (
    SELECT line || '/' || REGEXP_SUBSTR(tags, '\[/ (.+?)\]', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS paths
    FROM t connect BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(tags, '\[/ (.+?)\]')
    ) s
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3db1/13/0)**:

```
|                                                         ALL_PATHS |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| [/home/pc/test/alseko][/home/pc/test/archive][/home/pc/test/logs] |
```